# CSS:before is not working on some elements, :after works just fine

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm using :before and :after to simulate an arrow. The :after on the code just fine, but adding :before doesn't, it doesn't even show up on the elements section of chrome DevTools.

I made sure there's content added. Also tried adding width, height, display:block, z-index just to test if it would show up.

The website: https://dev.radiusbridge.com/dis0319/
The codes are referring to the 2nd level menu items on the website mobile version. (991px and below)

This is the :after code that works well

```css
ul#menu-main-navigation > li > .sub-menu > li > .sub-menu > li > a.nav-link:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    background: #CDDC3C;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 15px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is the :before code that doesn't work

```css
ul#menu-main-navigation > li > .sub-menu > li > .sub-menu > li > a.nav-link:before {
    content: "\f105";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    color: #CDDC3C;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -23px;
    top: 5.45px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I expect the :before code to work like how the :after does.

PS: the before element doesn't show up on DevTools(Inspect Element)

Comment: I see both before and after on your site, one is the line the other is the arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS contains the following rule:

```
ul.sub-menu > li > a:before {
    display: none!important;
}
```

The selector matches the element and `!important` means it takes priority. DevTools has the annoying behavior of simply not showing pseudo elements that are not displayed.

Either adjust that rule or add `display: block!important` to your "arrow" rule.